# Find item in arbitrary-length array based on percentage

Tags: javascript

I have an array of images

```
var prizeImage;

//this is a dynamic amount
var result = 55; 

//the length of this array will change. Images will be added/removed
var prizeImageArray = ['image1.png','image2.png','image3.png','image4.png'] 


//I want to avoid having to type each of these if statements. 
if(result < 25){
    prizeImage = prizeImageArray[0];
}
if(result > 26 && result < 50){
    prizeImage = prizeImageArray[1];
}
if (result...)//and so on
```

The above is terrible code.

I want a method that will allow for the prize image array to change size and to avoid typing each of the if statements.

I hope this makes sense, I have a feeling it doesn't.

Comment: it shouldn't really matter. It can be any figure between 0 and 100.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you want to have a percent (from 0-100) and find out which image in your array is closest to that percent location and get that image URL.  If so, you can do that by dividing the percent by 100 to turn it into a decimal percentage, multiplying by the length of the array and then rounding that to an integer.  That gets you the array index that is closest to your percentage.  You can then index from the array to fetch the desired value.

You can do it like this:

```
function findPercentLocation(array, percent) {
    return(array[Math.round((percent / 100) * (array.length - 1))]);
}

var prizeImageArray = ['image1.png','image2.png','image3.png','image4.png'] 
var imageSrc = findPercentLocation(priceImageArray, 27);
```

If you want to make it more robust, you could protect against percent values outside the 0-100 range like this which would avoid extending beyond the bounds of your array:

```
function findPercentLocation(array, percent) {
    if (percent < 0) percent = 0;
    if (percent > 100) percent = 100;
    return(array[Math.round((percent / 100) * (array.length - 1))]);
}
```

Comment: If `percent` is 100 or just below 100, `Math.round((percent / 100) * array.length)]` will return the length of the array, which is an index that doesn't exist. You would rather do `Math.round((percent / 100) * array.length - 1)]`.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've written doesn't match anything for the values 25 or 26.

Try this, you can add or subtract one from percent to get it exact.

```
return prizeImageArray[Math.floor(percent/25)];
```

Answer (score -3):

The simplest solution would be to use the modulo operator. I've never written JavaScript, but I suppose the following code is syntactically correct.

```
prizeImage = prizeImageArray[result % 25];
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. It gives 0..24 for result ranging from 0..24. The poster wants all those to go to index 0.

Comment: Phrogz is right, but it is a terribly written question. So feel free to down vote me. TerjeR is wrong, but also quite new here ;)